# does anyone know how to get rid of "Firebase Hosting Setup Complete" screen when launching a firebase application?

Tags: javascript, firebase-hosting

recently ive launched my own firebase application, and I keep getting this error on my screen when I try to connect: "Firebase Hosting Setup Complete You're seeing this because you've successfully setup Firebase Hosting. Now it's time to go build something extraordinary! firebase" does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: You replace the files created by the setup process with your files and redeploy hosting. The path to the files is specified by the firebase configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

**step 1 :**
*delete this file:*

- build folder
- .firebase
- .firebaserc
- firebase.json
- package-lock.json
- package-lock.json

**step 2 :**
*run **firebase init** and follow this step :*

- What do you want to use as your public directory?   build
- Configure as a single-page app (rewrite all urls to /index.html)?
  Yes
- Set up automatic builds and deploys with GitHub?   No
- File build/index.html already exists. Overwrite?   Yes